# Ruby on Rails migrations run, schema.rb updated but changes not reflecting in psql database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

I have a ruby on rails application already running in production. The database has records which I do not want to loose. I had to add and run new migrations to add some new columns to existing tables. The migrations run successfully and the schema.rb file reflects the changes but the changes do not appear in the database or existing table structure.

Based on research online, `rake db:schema:load` updates the db based on the schema.rb file. But this resets the database.

It is crucial that I do not loose the data in the tables.Is there any way to solve this? I am fairly new to ruby on rails.

Comment: export the database first for backup. Then run the `schema:load`

Comment: By import, I guess you mean doing a pg dump and restoring the db with that? Shouldn't the migrate command automatically update the db structure?

Comment: Yes, pg dump and restore. In this way at least you don't lost the data.

Comment: Where did you run these migrations? Your development environment? Production? Both?

Comment: @muistooshort I ran it in both environments

Comment: I was able to fix it. I  checked the status of migrations in the production environment and realised they were down. I then run rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production and that did it. Changes now reflect in the db. Thanks @muistooshort for the nudge in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it. I  checked the status of migrations in the production environment `rake db:migrate:status RAILS_ENV=production` and realised they were down. I then run `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` and that did it. Changes now reflect in the db. Thanks @muistooshort for the nudge in the right direction